# Git: how to make a subfolder in a private repo as a public repo without splitting it out from the parent repo?

Tags: git, version-control, repository, subdirectory

I saw there are a lot of discussions talking about splitting a subfolder of an existing repository into a separate ***Git*** repository. My questions is can I just initialize a subfolder of an existing Git repository and push it to a remote place as a new one? I don't care whether the past history of the subfolder preserved in the new repo, but I actually only want to share the subfolder to allow people to contribute into it while let the parent Git project easily track all the changes in the subfolder.

More details: I have read through some methods using `Submodule`, but that is not what I want from my understanding. When I checkout my parent repo or internal collaborators pull the changes of the parent repo, I expect all changes from the subfolder to be synchronized as well. Maybe `subtree` neither work for me, but after reading over some posts online, I am actually not sure about my judgement. I prefer to have a simple solution, like just initialize the subfolder as a new folder and push... Does it work.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can I just initialize a subfolder of an existing Git repository and push it to a remote place as a new one?

No. Git-repo is monolithic object, any|all changes of tree *inside repo* aren't visible to external views as independent object

> Submodule, but that is not what I want from my understanding

You have to verify your understanding and fix it. Structuring by submodules assumes **supporting link** between states of parent repo and submodule, and this link reflect changes on both sides

Comment: thank you for responding this downvoted question as I am a newbie on Git and StackOverflow. Regarding submodule, do you mean if I make some changes in the submodule repo, does the parent repo also sees the changes and allow people to easily synchronize the changes without noticing there is a submodule attached? I feel subtree may serve the purpose better for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old question, you can check this: https://github.com/open-condo-software/gitexporter